# Google chrome closes tab when trying to open extensions settings

Tags: google-chrome

When I open Chrome settings I can look at either 'Settings', 'History', or 'About'.  However, if I click on 'Extensions' then that tab immediately closes.  This behavior only started within the last couple days and I didn't knowingly install any new extensions.

I looked in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions` to see if any of the extensions were unrecognizable but the directory names aren't usable; they're just random characters.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/1CpwkAXM) is the output of `find .` in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping there was a known add-on to remove but I guess not.  What did work to fix this was the typical uninstall/delete old config files/reinstall

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
#download and reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the reason why I was having this exat problem was a video downloader called Video download Helper. I just deleted it from the icon on the home page of the browser and everything was fine. No more spam tabs either.

Answer (score 0):

There are some malware which tend to create such problems. Once they are installed as an extension, it gets difficult to open "chrome://extensions" because every time one tries to open it, it closes the tab itself. The way out from this in Ubuntu is: 
 -- Open System Monitor
 -- Spot the chrome processes. There would be many processes besides the 
    one saying chrome because technically they are extensions. So, simply 
    try ending each such extra chrome process one by one. And every time, 
    try opening the "chrome://extensions". When each such process is 
    ended, chrome displays which extension has crashed. So, once the 
    malware extensions crashes while doing so, its name is displayed. And 
    then, when you try to open "chrome://extensions", it will work.
 -- Once opened, remove all such malware extensions from chrome.

Hope that was helpful. Happy browsing.